# Displaying pinyin over Chinese characters, without impacting word spacing

Tags: spacing, xetex, cjk, xecjk, chinese

I want to display pinyin (romanized form) over Chinese characters. However, the two methods I know (using `stackrel` or `tabular` both change the spacing between characters. This demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctexcap}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Heiti Std}
\newcommand{\mymacroone}[1]{$\stackrel{a}{\textrm{#1}}$}
\newcommand{\mymacrotwo}[1]{\begin{tabular}{l}a\\#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
    \Huge \noindent 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 \\
    \mymacroone{床}\mymacroone{前}\mymacroone{明}\mymacroone{月}\mymacroone{光}，\mymacroone{疑}\mymacroone{是}\mymacroone{地}\mymacroone{上}\mymacroone{霜}。\mymacroone{举}\mymacroone{头}\mymacroone{望}\mymacroone{明}\mymacroone{月}，\mymacroone{低}\mymacroone{头}\mymacroone{思}\mymacroone{故}\mymacroone{乡}。 \\
    \mymacrotwo{床}\mymacrotwo{前}\mymacrotwo{明}\mymacrotwo{月}\mymacrotwo{光}，\mymacrotwo{疑}\mymacrotwo{是}\mymacrotwo{地}\mymacrotwo{上}\mymacrotwo{霜}。\mymacrotwo{举}\mymacrotwo{头}\mymacrotwo{望}\mymacrotwo{明}\mymacrotwo{月}，\mymacrotwo{低}\mymacrotwo{头}\mymacrotwo{思}\mymacrotwo{故}\mymacrotwo{乡}。 \\
\end{document}
```

Each of the three lines should be displaying the same.

- With `stackrel`, the words are spaced too closely together. This problem is not created by `stackrel`. It is from having math mode with `textrm{}` inside.
- With `tabular`, the words are spaced too far apart, they do not properly break at the end of the line, and it has a strange vertical and horizontal alignment problems. Using `stackrel` would be ideal.

How can I place pinyin above Chinese characters without changing the spacing between the characters (at least in situations where the pinyin is shorter than the characters)?

Comment: Try your `tabular` with column specification `@{}l@{}` instead of just `l`. This removes the column separation (or spacing). I can't test it myself, since I don't have the appropriate editor installed.

Comment: When using `@{}l@{}`, the line using `tabular` appears with the same spacing as with `stackrel`.

Comment: @Village: Please add `cjk` tag if you use `xecjk` tag. Then the question would be easier to be find for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now I add another answer using LI Qing's [`xpinyin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpinyin) package.

It's rather easy to use:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{xpinyin}

\begin{document}
\Huge\sffamily

\begin{pinyinscope}
床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。
\end{pinyinscope}

\xpinyin*{床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I think the `ruby` package (from the `CJK` package bundle) would be useful here:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{ctexcap}

\usepackage{ruby}
% Sets size of the `ruby' i.e. pinyin annotation; default is 0.4
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.3}

\setCJKmainfont{Adobe Heiti Std}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
    \Huge \noindent 床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 \\    
\noindent\ruby{床}{chuáng}\ruby{前}{qián}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}\ruby{光}{guāng}，\ruby{疑}{yí}\ruby{是}{shì}\ruby{地}{dì}\ruby{上}{shàng}\ruby{霜}{shuāng}。
\ruby{举}{jǔ}\ruby{头}{tóu}\ruby{望}{wàng}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}，\ruby{低}{dī}\ruby{头}{tóu}\ruby{思}{sī}\ruby{故}{gù}\ruby{乡}{xiāng}。
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Pinyin annotation as rubies]

Comment: This solution is also giving different spacing from text without the `ruby` macros.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean... I think the `\ruby` macros produce boxes, thus `ctex` no longer see them as CJK characters and thus can't do the flexible word spacing thing. Sorry.

Comment: It's still a very good answer.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Which package do I need to install for Miktex to be able to use `\usepackage{ctexcap}`? So far I am getting: `! LaTeX Error: File `ctexcap.sty' not found.`

Comment: @Zelphir You want the "ctex" bundle -- http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctex

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thanks! I had to update my whole texlive (because of some l3kernel being too old or something), but now I got it working : )

Answer (score 8):

As LianTze Lim pointed out, [`ruby`](http://mirror.ctan.org/language/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.2/doc/ruby.txt) package in `CJK` bundle is specially designed for Japanese [ruby characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_character) and Chinese pinyin (拼音) or zhuyin (注音). However, it has some restrictions.

You can add `\CJKglue` at the end of the definition of `\ruby`, not only for proper spacing between Chinese characters, but also for correct line breaking. For example,

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{ruby}
\let\oldruby\ruby
\def\ruby#1#2{\oldruby{#1}{#2}\CJKglue}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.3}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\Huge\sffamily

床前明月光，疑是地上霜。举头望明月，低头思故乡。 

\ruby{床}{chuáng}\ruby{前}{qián}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}\ruby{光}{guāng}，%
\ruby{疑}{yí}\ruby{是}{shì}\ruby{地}{dì}\ruby{上}{shàng}\ruby{霜}{shuāng}。%
\ruby{举}{jǔ}\ruby{头}{tóu}\ruby{望}{wàng}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}，%
\ruby{低}{dī}\ruby{头}{tóu}\ruby{思}{sī}\ruby{故}{gù}\ruby{乡}{xiāng}。
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the result is still wrong sometimes: line break is allowed before punctuations now. And of course we have no puncutation spacing turning features then.

Although it is rather difficult to deal with all possible situations right now, we can do more if we use some TeX tricks (like `\futurelet`) and maybe hack into `xeCJK`. At least we can prevent linebreaking before punctuations:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysize{0.3}
\let\oldruby\ruby
\def\ruby#1#2{\oldruby{#1}{#2}\futurelet\next\addCJKglue}
\def\addCJKglue{\ifx\next\ruby \CJKglue \fi}

\begin{document}

\Huge\sffamily

床前明月光，疑是地上霜。

\ruby{床}{chuáng}\ruby{前}{qián}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}\ruby{光}{guāng}，%
\ruby{疑}{yí}\ruby{是}{shì}\ruby{地}{dì}\ruby{上}{shàng}\ruby{霜}{shuāng}。%

% Compare with old solution:
\def\ruby#1#2{\oldruby{#1}{#2}\CJKglue}
\ruby{床}{chuáng}\ruby{前}{qián}\ruby{明}{míng}\ruby{月}{yuè}\ruby{光}{guāng}，%
\ruby{疑}{yí}\ruby{是}{shì}\ruby{地}{dì}\ruby{上}{shàng}\ruby{霜}{shuāng}。%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a low level construction:

```
\newcommand{\mymacroone}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
        \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
        a\cr
        \noalign{\vskip-0.3ex}%
        \strut#1\cr}%
       }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: When I replaced `mymacroone` with your code, the spacing still has the same problem `stackrel` has. Yet, your illustration shows no problem.

Comment: @Village I said `\raggedright`; by inserting the characters in boxes you lose the peculiar spacing of Chinese. I can't see many other ways to proceed, though.

Comment: Adding `raggedright` to a line before the text places a line break after punctuation for all of the macros. Is there anything I can place outside of the macros that means, "Handle all of what inside this as Chinese text"?