# Strange spacing with ruby (furigana) package

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

If I use the ruby package to supply furigana for a kanji character, it seems to glue the characters right adjacent to the kanji closely together and preventing line breaks, creating odd and possibly excess spacing.

Is this a bug in the package and can I somehow fix it? Are there alternatives? (I found pxrubrica but that seems to be for platex only.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro}
%\setCJKmainfont{VL Gothic}

\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{-0.7em}

\begin{document}
\fbox{
\parbox{25em}{
\doublespacing
\ruby{青}{あお}いスーツ、\ruby{白}{しろ}いシャツ、\ruby{赤}{あか}いネクタイが\ruby{男}{だん}\ruby{性}{せい}\ruby{従}{じゆう}\ruby{業}{ぎよう}\ruby{員}{いん}\ruby{全
}{ぜん}\ruby{員}{いん}の\ruby{必}{ひつ}\ruby{需}{じゆ}\ruby{品}{ひん}だ。
}}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering of previous code]

Comment: I'm not surprised that hyphenation isn't possible when furigana is used. TeX hyphenates words, not sequences of boxes.

Comment: Tht `ruby` package is not fully compatible with `xeCJK`. Actually, the [`luatexja`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatexja) package is much better than `xeCJK` in Japanese typesetting. `luatexja` contains an addon package `luatexja-ruby`. It provides functionality of furigana annotation. You can check their manuals for details.

Answer (score 1):

`ruby` package is not implemented correct. I think this code piece will solve the problem:

```
\usepackage{ruby}
\let\oldruby\ruby
\def\ruby#1#2{\oldruby{#1}{#2}\futurelet\next\addCJKglue}
\def\addCJKglue{\ifx\next\ruby \CJKglue \fi}
```

See also [Displaying pinyin over Chinese characters, without impacting word spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38455/displaying-pinyin-over-chinese-characters-without-impacting-word-spacing)

Comment: It is tricky. `luatexja-ruby` is more powerful.

Comment: FWIW, in addition to your monkeypatch, I had to supply the package with the `nooverlap` option for proper rendering. Previously `nooverlap` and `overlap` did not seem to have much effect.

Comment: @QingLee: Indeed. But `luatexja-ruby` requires LuaTeX. It would be nice if some Japanese developer (e.g. 八登崇之) could provide a better solution for XeTeX.