# Furigana is misaligned in simple centered tabular cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Furigana seems misaligned in a simple tabular environment. Ruby hacks in MWE are from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206761/strange-spacing-with-ruby-furigana-package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{.4}
\let\oldruby\ruby
\def\ruby#1#2{\oldruby{#1}{#2}\futurelet\next\addCJKglue}
\def\addCJKglue{\ifx\next\ruby \CJKglue \fi}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\ruby{一}{いち}\ruby{日}{にち}%Correct
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\ruby{一}{いち}\ruby{日}{にち}\\%Furigana misaligned
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|m{10mm}|}
\hline
\ruby{一}{いち}\ruby{日}{にち}\\%Correct
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would like to understand why the most natural approach with `\begin{tabular}{|c|}` fails, and how to fix it (as I don't want to manually set up the column width).

[image: Ruby]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The ruby macro is basing its height on `\baselineskip` which is 0 in a `c` column, but you can set it using the `array` package `>` declaration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{.05ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{.4}
\let\oldruby\ruby
\def\ruby#1#2{\oldruby{#1}{#2}\futurelet\next\addCJKglue}
\def\addCJKglue{\ifx\next\ruby \CJKglue \fi}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\ruby{一}{いち}\ruby{日}{にち}%Correct
\begin{tabular}{|>{\baselineskip\normalbaselineskip}c|}
\hline
\ruby{一}{いち}\ruby{日}{にち}\\%Furigana misaligned
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|m{10mm}|}
\hline
\ruby{一}{いち}\ruby{日}{にち}\\%Correct
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick remedy! Thank you.

Comment: @Matsmath well thanks to your nice test file, allowed me to guess the answer with no knowledge of the macro at all:-)