# Improve a command for text annotation

Tags: macros, chinese

Inspired by LaTeX package `ruby` @egreg's suggestion to the problem ([Displaying pinyin over Chinese characters, without impacting word spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38455/displaying-pinyin-over-chinese-characters-without-impacting-word-spacing)) I implemented the following command with example of usage:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[heading]{ctex}
\newcommand{\annote}[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%\hfil
      ##\hfil\cr
      \strut#2\cr
      \noalign{\vskip-0.3ex}%
      \strut#1\cr}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\noindent \annote{床前}{In front my couch,} \annote{明月光，}{there's moonlight}\\
\annote{疑是地上霜。}{It looks like frost on the ground}\\
\annote{举头望}{Looking up} \annote{明月，}{the moon}\\
\annote{低头思}{Looking down missing} \annote{故乡。}{my hometown}

\end{document}
```

My purpose is to add an annotation to a text phrase. It seems working, but sometimes, I ran into a problem when compiling a LaTeX file with the command,
my Ubuntu machine would completely be frozen.

Would you please help me to review and improve?

Here is the output, when it works with XeLaTeX:

[image]

Comment: We'd need a failing example for debugging.

Comment: @egreg thanks! I'll try to collect it. By merely reviewing my adaptation of your suggestion, is there anything that I should improve? I almost zero experience of writing LaTeX macro.